# WordPress is not responding

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have a hacked WordPress site, where the attacker managed to exploit mailing system using php code, I cleaned the code but it seems the website is not responding as it used to be (http://heroleads.com/thailand)

I went through the logs and seems the php process is being killed, I can not figure out the issue

`Oct 23 07:07:41 leadhero lfd[46958]: *Suspicious Process* PID:46217 PPID:29512 User:herolead Uptime:75 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:07:41 leadhero lfd[46958]: *User Processing* PID:46920 Kill:0 User:herolead VM:245(MB) EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Oct 23 07:07:41 leadhero lfd[46958]: *User Processing* PID:46905 Kill:0 User:herolead VM:261(MB) EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Oct 23 07:08:41 leadhero lfd[47294]: *Suspicious Process* PID:46605 PPID:41522 User:herolead Uptime:114 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:08:41 leadhero lfd[47294]: *Suspicious Process* PID:46855 PPID:35891 User:herolead Uptime:75 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:09:41 leadhero lfd[47837]: *Suspicious Process* PID:47213 PPID:29156 User:herolead Uptime:75 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:09:41 leadhero lfd[47837]: *User Processing* PID:47657 Kill:0 User:herolead VM:273(MB) EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/wp-admin/admin.php
Oct 23 07:10:41 leadhero lfd[48098]: *Suspicious Process* PID:47758 PPID:44027 User:herolead Uptime:75 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:10:42 leadhero lfd[48098]: *User Processing* PID:48004 Kill:0 User:herolead VM:277(MB) EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Oct 23 07:11:42 leadhero lfd[48550]: *Suspicious Process* PID:48055 PPID:47692 User:herolead Uptime:75 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:11:42 leadhero lfd[48546]: *Email Queue* The exim delivery queue size is 85987
Oct 23 07:12:42 leadhero lfd[48834]: *Suspicious Process* PID:48498 PPID:46614 User:herolead Uptime:76 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:13:42 leadhero lfd[49101]: *Suspicious Process* PID:48785 PPID:43139 User:herolead Uptime:76 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:13:57 leadhero lfd[49334]: *Exceeded LOCALRELAY limit* from nfp (101 in the last hour)
Oct 23 07:14:42 leadhero lfd[49470]: *Suspicious Process* PID:48977 PPID:44027 User:herolead Uptime:76 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:15:42 leadhero lfd[49635]: *Suspicious Process* PID:49444 PPID:41522 User:herolead Uptime:76 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:15:42 leadhero lfd[49635]: *User Processing* PID:49628 Kill:0 User:herolead VM:245(MB) EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Oct 23 07:16:42 leadhero lfd[50157]: *Suspicious Process* PID:49596 PPID:29156 User:herolead Uptime:76 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php
Oct 23 07:16:43 leadhero lfd[50155]: *Suspicious File* /tmp/index.php [leadhero:leadhero (508:506)] - Script, file extension`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to scan the website using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/ scan feature. I think there are some malwares inside your website. The Wordfence scan feature can detect common malwares and it's already helped me for many times.

Regards,

Adi

Comment: Thanks Adi, I already installed Wordfence. it did not show any error or hacks which find strange. I installed another plugin. lets see what will be the result

Answer (score 0):

Provided logs are LFD loges which are showing your site is using some extra memory and taking some time to execute php process on your server. I will suggest you please check your site with http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ and install BulletProof Security OR Wordfence Security plugins in your account to secure your site.

Also I can see you have root access so try to scan your account using maldet.

Comment: Wordfence did not show any result. I installed BulletProof lets see what it has to say. as for the maldetect this is the first time I know about it. I started the scan lets see what it has to say as well

Comment: Things got better but the site performance remains the same, this is what I still get


Oct 23 16:30:40 leadhero lfd[3675]: *Suspicious Process* PID:3471 PPID:1979 User:herolead Uptime:75 secs EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/herolead/public_html/thailand/index.php